# Hide Page Indicator Dot in WatchKit?

Tags: ios, watchkit

I'm new to native development on xcode and have gotten started working with WatchKit to put together a Watch extension for my HTML5 hybrid app. I'm trying to figure out how to hide the indicator dot on a page-based app view. It looks like the iOS analogue provides the ability to hide the dot, but I can't seem to find anything for WatchKit. The Apple reference site doesn't appear to indicate any such functionality, and don't see any config in the storyboard. I've Googled and searched on StackOverflow, and haven't found anything there either.

Is it possible to hide the page indicator dot on a page-based app view? If so, how might I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently not possible to hide page indicator.